# Why is my app stuck on an endless loading screen?

Tags: flash

If you are a Flash developer, this post is for you!

https://web.archive.org/web/20160720065931/http://missionmonstre.telequebec.tv/game/BradysBeasts_fr.html

Found a game I loved has a kid. Installed Ruffle and everything seems to load. However, I can't get past the loading screen. The game worked when the website was still online. However, now, I can't seem to make it work?

Anyone is able to help me debug this?

Comment: **Ruffle** has a pretty low compatibility with **AS1/2** and almost no compatibility with **AS3**: https://ruffle.rs/#compatibility I don't think there's any point to bother at the present moment, it is quite possible you won't be able to actually play **ANY** of the games you want.

Comment: @Organis Do you have any other way I can play Flash games? :/

Comment: Browse "flash" and "actionscript-3" questions, there are plenty of similar questions and no **convenient** answers.

Comment: @NicolasSC If you're on Windows you can try downloading the stand-alone Flash Player (exe file). See this [example article](https://www.howtogeek.com/438141/how-to-play-adobe-flash-swf-files-outside-your-web-browser/).